# nodeJS emilsedgh/modem library sp.SerialPort is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, constructor, serial-port, gsm, modem

I'm trying to run the example code https://github.com/emilsedgh/modem/blob/master/examples/send_sms.js and I get:

```
node_modules/modem/lib/modem.js:82
    modem.port = new sp.SerialPort(device, {
                 ^
TypeError: sp.SerialPort is not a constructor
at EventEmitter.modem.open (node_modules/modem/lib/modem.js:82:22)
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/modem/examples/send_sms.js:15:7)
at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:607:3
```

Comment: Looks like you have a downrev `serialport` module.  Your `modem` module is using the syntax required by `serialport` version 4 and later, but your `serialport` module is behaving like version 3 or earlier.

Comment: downgraded the serialport library for nodeJS now getting this
    >> { '0': ' +CMS ERROR: 304' }
Error sending sms:  +CMS ERROR: 304

looking into it

Comment: I am able to send SMS successfully by using modem library, the mistake generating the 304 error was that I was using + sign for the phone number as opposed to usage details. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @MuhammadTahirSaleh which version of serial port did you use to make it work. I am also stuck with the same problem.